# How to make a right interaction between custom adapters in android?

Tags: android, listview

I write a simple test code about shopping. It's like in the picture.[add from right to left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDuNp.png)

It's simple. ListViews show 'Item's. The 'Item' has only name and count. On the right, I change the count and add the item to the cart on the left.

The main point is here, when I change the item's count that I added earlier and add the item again to the cart, all the same items in the cart and in the menu changes to the last count.

After I took the first picture, I changed the same item's count and added it again. So, two items in the cart have same last count. I can't understand the mistake in the code. [Second screenshot after added the same item with different count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSb8c.png)

Thanks in advance.

I found something about the code. All the ArrayLists are acting like they are static. If I change the onClick metot of add button in the menu as:

```
ImageButton ekle = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
ekle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //After changing this row, all the ArrayList's (menu and cart) items 
        //in this position is changing to the same number 5.
        //And I delete the EditText's TextChangeListener, as well.
        menu.get(position).setCount(5);
        ((BaseAdapter) context.list1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

---

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private int count;

    public Item(String s, int i) {
        name = s;
        count = i;
    }

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public int getCount() {return count;}
    public void setName(String s) {name = s;}
    public void setCount(int i) {count = i;}
}
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView list1;
ListView list2;
static ArrayList<Item> menu = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<Item> cart = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    menu.add(new Item("Item1", 1));
    menu.add(new Item("Item2", 1));
    menu.add(new Item("Item3", 1));
    menu.add(new Item("Item4", 1));
    menu.add(new Item("Item5", 1));

    list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    list1.setAdapter(new CartAdapter(this, cart));
    list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
    list2.setAdapter(new MenuAdapter(this, menu));
}
}
```

---

```
public class CartAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
MainActivity context;
ArrayList<Item> cart;

public CartAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Item> m) {
    context = (MainActivity) activity;
    cart = m;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cart.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return cart.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);

    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    name.setText(cart.get(position).getName());

    EditText count = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    count.setText("" + cart.get(position).getCount());
    return view;
}
}
```

---

```
public class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
MainActivity context;
ArrayList<Item> menu;

public MenuAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Item> m) {
    context = (MainActivity) activity;
    menu = m;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return menu.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return menu.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list2, null);

    ImageButton ekle = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    ekle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.cart.add(menu.get(position));
            ((BaseAdapter) context.list1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    name.setText(menu.get(position).getName());

    EditText miktar = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    miktar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (count != 0) {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                Item item = menu.get(position);
                item.setCount(i);
                MainActivity.menu.set(position, item);

                CharSequence text = menu.get(position).getName() +" : "+ menu.get(position).getCount();
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem. The both ArrayLists act like static (but they are not!). So I changed the decleration of the Item class, made count final. And that's it, problem is solved.

```
public class Item 
{
private String name;
private final int count;

public Item(String s, int i) {
    name = s;
    count = i;
}

public String getName() {return name;}
public int getCount() {return count;}
public void setName(String s) {name = s;}
}
```